# How to save WorkMail email attachment to tmp location and push to s3 in lambda using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

I want to push my email attachment to s3 bucket using python, my following piece of code doing that task but when new email hits with different file name this is not working.

I want to upload any dynamic name and extension to the s3 bucket.

I am new bee in python.

Thanks in advance.

```
# Write the attachment to a temp location
    open('/tmp/filename.csv', 'wb').write(attachment.get_payload(decode=True))
```

Comment: What is the actual question? For dynamic names, use a dynamic variable - can you please explain the actual issue you are facing with some more code so that this is reproducible?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I am receiving new email everyday with different file names and that file I want to push to the S3 bucket based on subject line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to extract the attachment from the lambda:

```
def get_attachment(msg, content_type):
"""
Moves through a tree of email Messages to find an attachment.
:param msg: An email Message object containing an attachment in its Message tree
:param content_type: The type of attachment that is being searched for
:return: An email Message object containing base64 encoded contents (i.e. the attachment)
"""
attachment = None
msg_content_type = msg.get_content_type()

if ((msg_content_type == content_type or msg_content_type == 'text/plain')
        and is_base64(msg.get_payload())):
    attachment = msg

elif msg_content_type.startswith('multipart/'):
    for part in msg.get_payload():
        attachment = get_attachment(part, content_type)
        attachment_content_type = attachment.get_content_type()

        if (attachment and (attachment_content_type == content_type
                            or attachment_content_type == 'text/plain')
                and is_base64(attachment.get_payload())):
            break
        else:
            attachment = None

return attachment
```

Its described here: https://medium.com/caspertechteam/processing-email-attachments-with-aws-a35a1411a0c4